# Measuring apparent length of object (in pixels) using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, blender

I have used [blender](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi5wKyFxLHtAhWb7HMBHdpkA8QQmhMwJnoECCMQAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBlender_(software)&usg=AOvVaw39MwILlL6HzOyDSeWPx8G2) to render different images of my 3D object from different angles/poses. The object has colored edges (as shown in the image).

[image]

Now, I aim to measure the length of the orange and blue edge (**Lo and Lb**) in pixels, using OpenCV. Had the edge been made of a single pixel (i.e., a line made of a single edge), it would be an easy task. But, this is not the case here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Threshold on color using cv2.inRange(). Then get the contour. Then get the rotated bounding box using cv2.minAreaRect(). That will return the length width and angle for that region. Do the same for the other color.

Comment: ask user to pick points? get blender to dump the corners of your object after projection to screen?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I couldn't get it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way in Python OpenCV.

```
 - Read the input
 - Threshold on one of the colors
 - Apply morphology to close gap
 - Get the contour
 - Get the rotated rectangle
 - Get the length from the rotated rectangle
 - Compute the centerline length
 - Draw the rotated rectangle on the input
 - Draw the centerline on the input
 - Save the results
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# read image
img = cv2.imread("blender.png")

# get color bounds of brown
lower =(0,30,60) # lower bound for each channel
upper = (20,50,80) # upper bound for each channel

# create the mask and use it to change the colors
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# apply morphology
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get contour
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
cntr = contours[0]

# get rotated rectangle from contour
rot_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cntr)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rot_rect)
box = np.int0(box)

# draw rotated rectangle on copy of img
rot_bbox = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(rot_bbox, [box], 0, (255,255,255), 1)

# get dimensions
(center), (width,height), angle = rot_rect

# print dimensions
print('length=', height)
print('thickness=', width)

# get center line from box
# note points are clockwise from bottom right
x1 = (box[0][0] + box[3][0]) // 2
y1 = (box[0][1] + box[3][1]) // 2
x2 = (box[1][0] + box[2][0]) // 2
y2 = (box[1][1] + box[2][1]) // 2

# draw centerline on image
center_line = img.copy()
cv2.line(center_line, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255,255,255), 1)

# compute center line length
cl_length = math.sqrt( (x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 )
print('centerline_length',cl_length)

# write img with red rotated bounding box to disk
cv2.imwrite("blender_thresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("blender_morph.jpg", morph)
cv2.imwrite("blender_rot_rect.jpg", rot_bbox)
cv2.imwrite("blender_length.jpg", center_line)


# display it
cv2.imshow("THRESHOLD", thresh)
cv2.imshow("MORPH", morph)
cv2.imshow("BBOX", rot_bbox)
cv2.imshow("CENTLINE", center_line)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Morphology image:

[image]

Rotated Rectangle on input:

[image]

Centerline on input:

[image]

Measurements:

```
length= 488.6615295410156
thickness= 9.058079719543457
centerline_length 488.83637344207517
```

Comment: This looks very neat. Can it be applied to non structured edges (like the other 3 edges) ?

Comment: Yes it you can threshold them by color with morphology to clean it up into one line or quadrilateral. If you can do that, you can get the rotated bounding box. Or if they are thin enough, just count the non-zero pixels. Looking closely at your original, the blue and green regions are fine, but the top red edge, is not a clean, constant red. It blends from red to white.

Comment: Another approach would be to threshold on the large main quadrilateral region. Then get the contours, then reduce the number of vertices to a proper 4 sided quadrilateral using approxPolyDP(). Then compute the length of the 4 sides from the vertices.