# How to detect the centerline from edges of a shape?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

[The unfiltered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbYWa.jpg)I have a 2D image of a vessel in grayscale and I want to convert it to a 3D model for further analysis.
I’ve imported it using opencv (`cv2`) library and I’ve written a code for detecting the edges of the shape in the image.
But, I have some problem with detecting the center-line by using the edges coordinates.I want the center-line for revolving the shape and convert it to a 3D model)

I appreciate any help.

Here is the image but as you can see the line hasn't been fitted to the middle of the shape.

[image]

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Applying the bilateral blur to the image
img = cv2.imread('vessel.png')
blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(img,9,75,75)

#Applying the Canny edge detection to the blurred image to find the edges
edges = cv2.Canny(blur,100,200)

#Getting the coordinateof the pixels
x , y = np.where(edges > 0.5) 

#Getting the regression line (slope and intercept)
m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, deg=1)

#Drowing the line in the image 
edges_img = cv2.line(edges, (int(0 * m + b), 0), (int(500*m+b), 500) , color = (255,0,0) , 
thickness = 2)

#plotting the result  in comparison with the raw image

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(blur,cmap = 'gray')

plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges_img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()`
```

Comment: please post the unfiltered data.

Comment: See my solution for getting the centerline from the rotated bounding box at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123555/measuring-apparent-length-of-object-in-pixels-using-opencv/65132154#65132154

Comment: THe 2D image gives no hint as to what the body/figure looks like.

Comment: the unfiltered image's been added